# Proper way to connect clients/servers for UDP broadcast

Tags: c

So I try to achieve that `1` ESP can send a UDP package to `N` ESP's.

What I have done:

- Created a client who connects to the `255.255.255.255` and sends packages
- Created N servers which bind to `0.0.0.0` and are listening

I know my servers works, when I send packages over the terminal it receives.

I think something is wrong in the cliencode:

```
struct sockaddr_in send_addr;
send_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
//send_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( "255.255.255.255" );
inet_aton( "255.255.255.255", &send_addr.sin_addr );
send_addr.sin_len = sizeof(send_addr);
send_addr.sin_port = htonl(6001);

int sock = ::socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP );

int flag = 1;
setsockopt( sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &flag, sizeof(flag) );

// fails when I try to bound it to 255.255.255.255
connect( sock, (const struct sockaddr*)&send_addr, sizeof(sock) ); 

int send_buf[32]; // filled with data

while(1)
{
  sendto( sock, send_buf, 32, 0,
     (const struct sockaddr*)&send_addr, sizeof(send_addr) );
}

// EDIT1 
on the other side the servers are listening
```

Any help appreciated.
I compile with C++ dunno whether this makes a difference.

EDIT1:
I also tried without the connect I don't get a connection error then, and no send error (correct size is written to the socket), but no msg at server(s) side.

I send my terminal package with

`echo -e "msg" | socat - UDP_DATAGRAM:255.255.255.255:6001,broadcast`

Don't know what it does in the background, but this would help a lot if I knew.

Comment: What does the word "connection" mean in the context of udp?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/udp-client-server-using-connect-c-implementation/  
In this example they are connecting the udp client socket, but to a specific client not to the broadcast addr

Comment: Try binding the socket to a specific network interface.

Comment: Thats a bit tricky, but I will try to find out how I get the interface name on my esp32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the error. It was not related to my code.

It seems like my esp32 (wroom) is not capable of sending packages with a size > 4096.

Reducing the package size gives me correct results.

Have to dig further maybe there is some config which can be set for this problem.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The maximum packet size on most systems is 1472 for udp. This fits I to a standard ethernet frame of 1500. Larger datagrams may be split and reassembled but if one part is lost the other parts are discarded. So datagram sizes below 1472 bytes

Comment: Thank you, now this makes more sense.